# Why in my IDE my indentation expands my code(parameters) like this

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-styles

I'm working in android studio but whenever I do `ctrl + alt + L` , it auto indents the code but collapses most of code like this

[image]

When there is also space at the right to fulfill the rest of the code

How to fix this in the IDE ?

I would like it to be like this

[image]

Thanks

Comment: It expands the code like this because it is easy to understand when you have multiple parameters with complex names, so it is recommended to do it like this.

Comment: Which android studio version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default code style limits each line to 100 characters.

If you want to change it go into Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Kotlin, then inside `Wrapping and Braces` tab you will find `Hard wrap at` (default: 100).

You can also go to Settings -> Editor -> Appearance and check `Show hard wrap guide` that will display a vertical line at hard wrap limit so you will know where auto-formatting is going to break your code into multiple lines.